Method does not exist or incorrect signature Expression cannot be assigned
This is the error:
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getOcpIntegration(Account) from the type OCPDataRestCallOut (161:54)
force-app\main\default\classes\OrderDataTest.cls  Expression cannot be assigned
Test method snippet:
 Account acc2 = new Account(Brand__c = 'TNF'
                                   , Country__c = 'GB'
                                   , LastName = 'AccTriggerTest_001'
                                   , PersonEmail = 'AccTriggerTest_001@test.com'
                                   , RecordTypeId = AccountUtils.NonRegisteredCustomerRecordTypeId());

        OCPIntegration__mdt ocp = OCPDataRestCallOut.getOcpIntegration(acc2);

method:
public static OCPIntegration__mdt getOcpIntegration(Account acc){
    if(acc == null || string.isblank(acc.Brand__c) || string.isblank(acc.Country__c)) return null;
    String siteId = string.format('{0}_{1}',new List<object>{acc.Brand__c, acc.Country__c}).toUpperCase();
    OCPIntegration__mdt ocpMetaList = OCPIntegration__mdt.getInstance(siteId);
    if(ocpMetaList != null && !string.isblank(acc.Language__c) && !string.isblank(acc.Country__c)){
       OCPIntegration__mdt clone = ocpMetaList.clone();
       clone.Locale__c = string.format('{0}_{1}',new List<object>{acc.Language__c?.toLowerCase(), acc.Country__c?.toUpperCase()});
       return clone;
    }
    return ocpMetaList;


The error suggests that the latest version of OCPDataRestCallOut hasn't been saved to the server successfully. Try deploying it again, and observe if you get any error messages. This method appears to be correct, at least with regards to syntax, so is not likely the problem.

Re deployed OCPDataRestCallOut - same error.

@user149369 Check if your method deployed successfully by opening the class from developer console. Or please share the full code here https://www.decodeforce.com/code

@sfdcfox - correct, I was using the old version and the method was missing. Updated and incorrect signature error is gone.
